# Issue while copying a range from a workbook to another : reference to old workbook appears in the formula

Tags: excel, vba

I have a source workbook with only one sheet `Sheet1` with :

- Cell `C2` is named "DEUX" (name relative to sheet `Sheet1`) and contains the number 2
- Cell `D2` contains the number 3
- Cell `C3` is named "RESULT" (name relative to sheet `Sheet1`) and contains the formula "=DEUX+Sheet1!D2" (which gives 5)

This source workbook is in `path1`. I have a copy of the source woorkbook at `path2`, the target workbook. In it I added the following macro :

```
Public Sub CpyRange()

    Dim pathToSource As String
    pathToSource = "path1" 'the aforementionned path to source workbook
    Dim wkbSource As Workbook
    Set wkbSource = Workbooks.Open(pathToSource & "Source.xlsx")
    Dim wksSource As Worksheet
    Set wksSource = wkbSource.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Dim rangeToCopy As Range
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Set rangeToCopy = wksSource.Range("RangeToCopy")
    rangeToCopy.Copy
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("RangeToCopy").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    wkbSource.Close

End Sub
```

(Without the `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` bit, when the macro was run, I was having pop-ups "A formula or sheet you want to move or copy contains the name DEUX" etc. Now I don't have them which is what I want.)

But I have a problem after running the macro : in cell `C3` of sheet `Sheet1` of the target workbook I have the formula : "=DEUX+'path1[Source.xlsx]Sheet1'!D2" where `path1` is the windows path to the source wokbook.

I would like to have the same formula as in the source workbook, that is : "=DEUX+Sheet1!D2".

*This is an example isolating the problem that I have in a real setup where the range `RangeToCopy` is huge, millions of cells with several hundred of thousands of formulas in it.* So how would I achieve this simply ?

**Remark.** I have `Sheet1!D2` and not `D2` just to model that in the real setup the cell is in another sheet from the same workbook.

Comment: Not really an answer but why isn't your original formula just `"=DEUX+D2"`?

Comment: if you have the same ranges & range names in all workbooks just use "=DEUX+Sheet1!D2" as formula an avoid copy paste.

Comment: Find and Replace if the paths are the same.

Comment: @SJR See the remark I added at the end of the question.

Comment: @ALOXAZ Because in the real setup, the range I copy has millions of cells, and hundreds of thousands of cells containing formulas (as I wrote in the question, btw) so what you propose wouldn't be tractable.

Comment: If you are copying millions of cells you might want to re-think what your apporach.

Comment: @SRJ That's the classic IT answer :) More seriously : except my problem of sheet reference, copying a range of millions of cells with values and hundred of thousands of formula cell doesn't take much time **at all**. This not a valid argument for me to "rethink my approach".

Comment: I don't agree. I think it is a valid argument! Anyway, as I said before either use Find and Replace to remove the paths or write some code to scan all cells containing formulae for square brackets and remove everything before the "]". There are probably examples online.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
Sub test5()

Dim Total As Long

Total = Application.Sum(Range("DEUX").Value, Sheet1.Range("D2").Value)

End Sub
```

Comment: You can easily imagine that in my real setup this wouldn't help at all, see comments

Answer (score 0):

You can try an easy, simple way <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> and replace all `path1[Source.xlsx]` with `""`